# Photon acting like a wave

Tags: waves, photons, double-slit-experiment

Is it possible that photons (in a double slit experiment) are not the only force/object emitted from the source which is not detectible. Thus with the photon comes a force like a wave wherein the photon is carried in, thus making the particle ACT like a wave but it is actually a particle IN a wave we cannot detect. This would explain that when you observe the photon through the observing technics the wave is blocked but the particle still passes through the observing item causing the effect, that when it is observed, it changes behavior but it is actually not changing behavior its just not in the wave anymore and thus not acting like a wave.

Comment: [de Broglie-Bohm interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory)

Comment: It's called wavefunction ;)

Comment: Also check out Pilot Wave theory.(modern version of de Broglie-Bohm)